# Inserting an integer value in string.format

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

what is the process for insert value of a in string.format

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace NepaliDateConverter
    {
        public partial class Form2 : Form
        {
           static public string[] weeks = { "आईतबार", "सोमबार", "मंगलबार", "बुधबार", "बिहीबार", "शुक्रबार", "शनिबार" };
           int a = (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
           **string b= string.Format("{a}", weeks);**
```

Comment: are you stuck at `C# 4.0`? Can you use `C# 6`?

Comment: What do you want to do? Your `weeks` variable contains a collection of strings, your `string.Format` call puts one thing into a string. Can you show what you'd like as output? You may want to look at the `StringBuilder` class or perhaps the `string.Join` method

Comment: do you want to have weeks of "a" in a word? let's say day of week is 5, you want to have the fifth data in `weeks` which is "शुक्रबार"?

Answer (score 2):

[String.Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Format_System_String_System_Object_):

```
string b = string.Format("{0}", weeks[a])
```

OR

```
string b = weeks[a];
```

Comment: i got it.
thank you brother